# Modifying dictionary to remove items

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a python dictionary like below:

```
j = {'a':'b', 
'c':'d', 
'e':'f', 
'd':'g', 
'h':'i', 
'b':'j', 
'g':'k'}
```

The key is the old_id and the value is the new_id.
A few of the values are again repeated as keys, as and when the new_id is updated again.
I want to update the dictionary such that the keys have the latest values.

I want my new dictionary to look like this:

```
j = {'a':'j',
'c':'k',
'e':'f',
'd':'k',
'h':'i',
'b':'j',
'g':'k'
}
```

PS: Please note this is just sample data.
I have only the initial dictionary available to me.

Comment: I do not understand nor see a connection between the desired output and the original dict.

Comment: @user56700 `a : b` and `b : j` therefore `a : j` for instance.

Comment: cause c:d -> d:k so c:k

Comment: Is the result `'c':'d'` due to the original dictionary mapping `'c':'d'`, then `'d': 'g'` and finally `'g':'k'`?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to do it in-place (i.e. your replacements should be counted earlier while iterating the dict (be aware that ordered dicts by default aren't a thing before cpython 3.6)), you can do something like:

```py
j = {'a':'b', 
    'c':'d', 
    'e':'f', 
    'd':'g', 
    'h':'i', 
    'b':'j', 
    'g':'k'}

converted = {}
    
for d_key in j:
    current = d_key
    
    while current in j:
        current = j[current]

    converted[d_key] = current

print(converted)
```

The `current` part tracks the replacement until exhausting (when the new key is no longer in the table.

If you want to do it inplace, replace `converted` with `j` - you should be fine as long as you only work with the keys and don't add any new keys (modifying a structure while iterating over it is usually no-no).

Answer (score 1):

Just do a loop and keep checking if value present as key in dictionary. if it is not then update the value with that value otherwise go with the loop again

```
j = {'a':'b', 
'c':'d', 
'e':'f', 
'd':'g', 
'h':'i', 
'b':'j', 
'g':'k'}


for k, v in j.items():
    while v in j:
        v = j[v]
    j[k]= v
print(j)
```

output

```
 {'a': 'j', 
 'c': 'k',
 'e': 'f',
 'd': 'k',
 'h': 'i',
 'b': 'j',
 'g': 'k'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k in j.keys(): 
     for k2 in j.keys(): 
        if j[k] == k2: 
           j[k] = j[k2]
```

So you go through all keys (k2) and test if any value matches with k if they do you replace them. So O(n²), not really efficient. But it works.